# Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to two 'T' operands

Tags: swift, generics, computed-properties

```
struct PickerRange<T: Comparable> {
    var start: T
    var end: T
    var step: T

    var length: T {
        // Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to two 'T' operands.
        return max(start, end) - min(start,end) / step 
    }
}
```

Error is generated when creating computed properties. How to fix?

Comment: Think of it this way: `T` can be *anything* comparable. How do you divide two strings?

Comment: Please include code as text to your questions. 

Comment: @the4kman: `T` must be only a number, if I specify `struct PickerRange<T: Numeric>` - same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply specify one of the `Numeric` protocols.

For floating point precision:

```
struct PickerRange<T:FloatingPoint> {
    var start: T
    var end: T
    var step: T

    var length: T {
        return max(start, end) -  (min(start,end) / step)
    }
}
```

`SignedInteger`, `UnsignedInteger` or other `Numeric` protocols are also an option.

// **`Comparable`**

Neither of these require of you to specify `Comparable` additionally, so specifying one of these is suffice for the case.

**EDIT:**

> How to make one structure for Int and Double?

Essentially, you **can**, by specifying SignedNumeric:

```
struct PickerRange<T:SignedNumeric & Comparable> {
    var start: T
    var end: T
    var step: T
}

// Treated as PickerRange<Double>
let a = PickerRange(start: 1.0, end: 5.0, step: 1)

// Treated as PickerRange<Int>
let b = PickerRange(start: 1, end: 5, step: 1)
```

However, you have specialized `length` property, which includes `/` operator not supported by `SignedNumeric`. A workaround would consist in type-checking/force-casting to a type you have initialized your struct with:

```
struct PickerRange<T:SignedNumeric & Comparable> {
    var start: T
    var end: T
    var step: T

    var length: T {
        if T.self is Double.Type {
            return (max(start, end) as! Double) - ((min(start, end) as! Double) / (step as! Double)) as! T
        } else if T.self is Int.Type {
            return (max(start, end) as! Int) - ((min(start, end) as! Int) / (step as! Int)) as! T
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
}

let a = PickerRange(start: 1.0, end: 5.0, step: 1)
let b = PickerRange(start: 1, end: 10, step: 1)

print(a.length)
print(b.length)
```

Comment: How to make one structure for Int and Double? If I do `struct PickerRange<T:FloatingPoint & SignedNumeric>` that `let range = PickerRange<Int>(start: 1, end: 5, step: 1)` get an error: Type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'FloatingPoint'

Comment: I'm afraid this is impossible, because `/` is essentially a function applied to two instances of particular type. `SignedNumeric` protocol alone does not have its definition, `FloatingPoint` or `SignedInteger` do. There's a workaround to this. You would need to check for particular type and make forced-cast and then call required functionality. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Done. Check it out.